# error while using FREAK

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, freak

I'm trying to create Descriptor extractor using FREAK. but 
at the following line:
`freakExtractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('FREAK')`

I get an error saying:
`freakExtractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('FREAK')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DescriptorExtractor_create'`

can someone tell me what is the exact problem and why i'm getting this error?

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 with opencv 2.4.3 and python 2.7.

Comment: It worked for me. Not getting any errors. Try using "SIFT", "STAR" instead of "FREAK"

Comment: And just to make sure check the version of your python opencv again. print cv2.__version__

Comment: @Froyo the AttributeError would clearly indicate there is no function called DescriptorExtractor_create. vineetrok: try to 'print dir(cv2)' and see if the function is inside.

Answer (score -2):

I think,

```
cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('FREAK')
```

is not a part of python interface, just use the latest opencv for that then it will work or you simply can write the code in c++ which is availabe in that version in c++.